# Animating circle clip on D3 Geo Azimuthal

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm messing around with a version of d3.geo.azimuthal as seen here: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/azimuthal.html

I have a list of links that navigate to particular continents. These each call a custom function navigateGlobe with info on where to move to.

```
function navigateGlobe(orig, scal) {
    projection.origin(orig);
    projection.scale(scal);
    refresh(1500);
}
```

The refresh function is the same as in the source example, and looks like this:

```
function refresh(duration) {
    (duration ? feature.transition().duration(duration) : feature).attr("d", clip);
}
```

On running navigateGlobe, it works correctly and the projection smoothly transitions to the required location and scale, however the clipping circle would not be updated until the next move of the globe by the mouse. I know that the clipping is done by the circle, to hide countries on the side of the globe facing away from the user, so I altered my function:

```
function navigateGlobe(orig, scal) {
    projection.origin(orig);
    projection.scale(scal);
    circle.origin(orig); // Need to animate this!
    refresh(1500);
}
```

The clipping circle now updates but does so immediately, ie the destination clipping point is reached on step 1 of animation. I would like to know if there's a way of transitioning the clipping circle at the same rate as the projection so that the entire animation looks smooth.

For reference, again as in the source example, var circle is set up as:

```
var circle = d3.geo.greatCircle()
    .origin(projection.origin());
```

I will try to set up a fiddle as an example of what is going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is an example where D3's transitions fall a bit short -- you can't really transition just values. You can set up your own easing function, but you'll need to call it manually with the right values.

To do this, you would set up an [interpolation function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_interpolate) between the old and new origins. Then, you would call `navigateGlobe` with intermediate origins recursively with `setTimeout` in the following fashion.

```
var interpolator = d3.interpolate(...);
var iters = 10;
function setNewOrigin(count) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        navigateGlobe(interpolator(count/iters));
        if(count < iters) setNewOrigin(count + 1);
    }, 10);
}
setNewOrigin(1);
```

The duration of this transition is determined by the number of iterations (here 10) and the timeout value for the recursive call (here 10ms, i.e. total 100ms). The total would need to be the same as for your other transition.

Comment: I took a variation of this and have got something reasonable now, so I'll mark this as answered. Unfortunately the only way I could find to do it was use the interpolators for animating scale and origin for the projection at the same time as the origin for the clipping circle. This takes away the nice easing effect you get with a transition. Is there any way to get this back? (I have seen that there is something called "basis" interpolation that looks like it'll do what I want it to do, however I don't think I can apply it on the interpolation here)

Comment: Can't really tell whether easing would be possible without seeing the code. It might be good if you asked a separate question about this.

Comment: I couldn't see an inbuilt easing function I could use but I made my own, rather than the linear setNewOrigin(count+1) recursion, it does a (count+i), where i increases from 0 until count > iters/2, then decreases back to 0. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: There are several builtin easing functions in D3. Are those not suitable?

Answer (score 0):

this actually works, based on all what's been suggested, using requestAnimationFrame

```
    var o = projection.origin();

    var si = d3.interpolate(projection.scale(), SCALE);
    var xi = d3.interpolate(o[0], -58.4459789 +10);
    var yi = d3.interpolate(o[1], -34.612869   -4); // buenos aires -4°

    function xanimate (fn, time) {
        var start = null;

        function step(timestamp) {
            var progress;
            if (start === null) start = timestamp;
            progress = timestamp - start;
            var p = progress / time;
            fn (p);
            if (progress < time) {
                requestAnimationFrame(step);
            }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }

    function navigateGlobe(orig, scal) {
        projection.origin(orig);
        projection.scale(scal);
        circle.origin(orig); // Need to animate this!
        refresh();
    }

    xanimate (function (t) {
        navigateGlobe ([xi(t), yi(t)], si(t));
    }, 2000);
```